# MS Access A certain Form's Form_Load() Only invoked first time that the user views said forms, but fails to be invoked in future viewings

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, load

I have very a rudimentary understanding of Microsoft Access and VBA Code.
On my work desktop, I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access
I've been tasked to create a MS Access application with an Access DB.

In the Visual Basic files, I have pseudo-code behind files for the various MS Access forms.

Most of my MS Access forms files have a subroutine like the following one:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()

     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdfSelectQuery As DAO.queryDef
     Dim argumentsStringArray() As String

  If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then

     argumentsStringArray = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")

    …...Blah blah initialize some variables using the argumentsStringArray Blah blah …..;
  End If

 End Sub
```

Now the "Navigation" within the application can move back and forth between different forms, and it could go back to an earlier form that was already seen/used by the user of  the application.

A Particular Form's Form_Load() subroutine  does get executed the very first time that said form runs within the context of a particular execution run of said MS Access Application.  However, if the application navigates back to a particular form that the user has already seen then it will **Not** execute said  Form_Load() subroutine.

Could someone please tell me what code modifications that I would have to make in order to ensure that a Particular Form's Form_Load() subroutine executes regardless of how many times the user has seen it?

Comment: If the form remains open, then it is only loaded once, you'll need another event. `Private Sub Form_GotFocus()` perhaps.

Comment: ok, could you please tell me what the other event handler method is supposed to be?  Also, I navigate between forms(back and forth) using the  DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="BlahBlahFormCBlahbalha", OpenArgs:="assignedValue|" & assignedValue

Comment: Again, openargs, will only be passed on opening.  If these come from other forms, maybe best to code to a) check form is open, b) get the value and write a function to do bits of code, and call them on open and focus.

Comment: You could set it up so that forms close whenever the user navigates away. That way the form will have to load when they navigate back.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be the following:

Instead of:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdfSelectQuery As DAO.queryDef
     Dim argumentsStringArray() As String

  If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then

     argumentsStringArray = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")

    …...Blah blah initialize some variables using the argumentsStringArray Blah blah …..;
  End If
 End Sub
```

You use:

```
Public Sub InitializeForm(SomeArgs As String)
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdfSelectQuery As DAO.queryDef
     Dim argumentsStringArray() As String
  If Len(SomeArgs) > 0 Then
     argumentsStringArray = Split(SomeArgs , "|")
    …...Blah blah initialize some variables using the argumentsStringArray Blah blah …..;
  End If
 End Sub
```

And instead of

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", OpenArgs := "Something"
```

You do

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
Forms!MyForm.InitializeForm "Something"
```

This allows way more flexibility than relying on `OpenArgs`, e.g. you can pass objects and strongly-typed values, return values, etc.

Comment: Could you please change Forms!MyForm.Initialize  to Forms!MyForm.InitializeForm  ?

Comment: @crazyTech Of course. You can use the edit button too if you want to do minor technical corrections to my answer.

Comment: Please don't use bangs. Bangs makes a complete lie of the code's behavior by implying that it's code but in fact it's just same thing as `Forms("MyForm")`, which will return an `Access.Form` rather than an `Form_MyForm`, which will not have the `Initialize` method at the compile time. Thus that method is late-bound. To ensure early-bound, assign to a variable of `Form_MyForm` type and call `Initialize` off the variable instead to get the early-bound behavior.

Comment: @this That's just semantics, the early and late-bound behavior are identical for this method. As the code doesn't need to store a reference to the form, I wouldn't dim and assign it, because that takes 3 lines for an operation that's just as easy to understand in a single line. Of course, `Forms("MyForm").InitializeForm` is valid too, but I generally don't use it since you need to use the bang notation when referring to forms from SQL, so I tend to use that notation everywhere for uniformity.

Comment: Nope. Delete the `Initialize` method off the `MyForm` and run the code. With the original code, you get a runtime error. The explicit assignment gets you a compile-time error. I'd always pick code that will yield compile-time error over runtime error. Always.

Answer (score 2):

The `Load` handler runs once in the lifetime of the object.

If you need it to run multiple times, don't reuse the same object. `DoCmd.OpenForm` works off the form's *default instance*, so unless you unload or otherwise destroy the instance, it remains loaded, and next time it's displayed it still holds whatever instance state it had when it was last dismissed.

If an Access form supports unloading (not familiar with Access, and can't test ATM), then `Unload MyForm` should unload it, making the `Load` event fire again the next time the form is referenced.

If you can `New` up a form and `Show` it like you could with a `UserForm`, do it - forms are objects in their own rights, and this global default instance stuff is hiding the *object* nature of it... making basic assumptions fail (like, a `Load` handler being expected to run every time the form is shown).

Alternatively, move your `Load` code into a new handler for the `Open` event, which would be invoked whenever the form is *open*, not merely *loaded*.

Comment: Access forms can be closed via `DoCmd.Close acForm, "FormName"`, instead of `unload` (but that throws an error if the form is not open, so you'd need to write code to detect if it's open). The `New` approach for Access has a few gotchas, such as the form being cleaned up as soon as the form object goes out of scope (and you can only pass `.OpenArgs` via `DoCmd.OpenForm` so this would require a rewrite anyway).

Comment: @ErikA "a few gotchas, such as the form being cleaned up as soon as the form object goes out of scope" - I would *expect* it to work like this. What makes forms flakey is that they're objects and yet Access seems adamant about treating them like global state.

Comment: When you do use a `New` instantiation, you do need to ensure you do not mix the access between the default instance and the new'd instance. That would certainly cause the flaky behavior. Because the newing is so rare, it is not very well understood and easily misused.